# How to remove duplicates from where in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code here

```
popular = Impression.select('impressionable_id, count(impressionable_id) as total').group('impressionable_id').order('total desc').limit(9)
@events = Event.where(id: popular.map(&:impressionable_id))
```

However what's happening at the moment is that the `@events` is returning duplicate names. I'm wondering how to return them without returning names that match.

### Update

Here's what I actually mean,

Basically `@events` is working fine, I can call `@events.eventname` and get 9 different events in the view.

However, if for example `Charity Fun Day` appears twice (has two different ids) I wouldn't want the event name to appear twice in this.

Comment: Can you explain: " @events is returning duplicate names" ... do you have multiple events with the same name?

Comment: We need a little more information. Are there different events (different IDs) for events with the same name? Can multiple Impressions linked to the same Event or vice versa?

Comment: Also (see the answer/comments below) what is the end result you're looking for? Nine unique events or any number of uniques based on nine impressions?

Comment: Sorry see Edit!

Comment: Use    events.where().distinct

Answer (score 0):

```
@events = Event.where(id: popular.map(&:impressionable_id)).uniq
```

Will give you unique Event items.

If there are Events that are different with the same names you can do

```
@events = Event.where(id: popular.map(&:impressionable_id))
@events.uniq{|event| event.name }
```

Comment: This will give unique events, but not nine unique events as seems to be the goal of the question.

Comment: He is only limiting Impressions to 9 no Events.

Comment: The purpose of which would seem to be to limit the events to nine, given the want for unique results. I suppose that's for OP to clarify.

Comment: Sure but if that was functioning to limit to 9 then it would still work in that manner.

Comment: Not if the nine impressions map to nine non-unique events, which is the fundamental problem here. @events.uniq will yield (9 - d) events, where d is the number of non-unique instances.

Comment: That is a fair criticism.